# sql server count distinct value of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I have 2 tables : `Contents` and `Packs`

In `Content` columns are like this:

```
Id    Name            IsPerishable     IsSpecial     IsDanger
----------------------------------------------------------
1     Paper           False            False         False
3     Fruit           True             False         False
5     NewsPaper       False            True          False
6     Radioactive     False            False         True
7     Foods           True             False         False
```

In `Packs` columns are like this:

```
Id      From        To      ContentId
---------------------------------------
1       ABZ         ATL     3
2       ANU         ATL     5
3       BAQ         ATL     7
4       BTS         BAQ     6
5       FRL         BAQ     5
```

Now I want a result that groups every 'To' then shows separate value of IsPerishable / IsSpecial / IsDanger

like this:

```
To      Perishable      Special        Danger
-----------------------------------------------
ATL     2                1               0
BAQ     0                1               1
```

I try use some query but none of them has worked correctly:

```
select Name, 
    case 
        when IsSpecial = 1 then count(IsSpecial) 
        when IsPerishable = 1 then count(IsPerishable) 
        when IsDanger = 1 then count(IsDanger) 
    end as 'Content'
from    Contents 
group by IsSpecial , IsPerishable , IsDanger

select       To,count(DISTINCt Id) as 'Count'
FROM         Packs
GROUP BY     To
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Select To,
     (Select count(*) from Content c where c.Id= p.Id and c.IsSpecial=1) as Special,
     (Select count(*) from Content c where c.Id= p.Id and c.Isperishable=1) as Perishable,
     (Select count(*) from Content c where c.Id= p.Id and c.Isperishable=1) as Danger
from
pack p
group by To
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.To, SUM(Perishable), SUM(Special),SUM(Danger) FROM
(
SELECT Id, 
CASE IsPerishable WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Perishable, 
CASE IsSpecial WHEN true then 1 ELSE 0 END AS Special, 
CASE IsDanger WHEN true then 1 ELSE 0 END AS Danger 
FROM Contents
) C 
Right Join Packs P 
on P.ContentId=C.Id
Group BY P.to
```

Comment: This is done using only 1 inner query and uses in built scalar SQL functions in outer query